# Why do LaTeX documents have a whacking great big space at the top?

Tags: latex

I am extremely new to LaTeX but have noticed that in the examples I have seen of LaTeX documents that there is always a massive number of empty lines at the top of the compiled pdf file. Nobody seems to say a word about this! Is this some kind of academic convention?

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\title{Here is my title}
\author{Kevin Wright}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    This is my abstract stuff
\end{abstract}
hello $\sqrt{x+y-10}$



\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you give an example? I can't remember having seen a document with excessive empty lines at the top.

Comment: I've added an example .tex file with the issue.

Comment: I wouldn't consider one or at most two empty lines in a row as massive number. Most people will put them in their document to make them more readable and separate logical blocks in the code.

Comment: It looks like about 15 or 16 lines to me.

Comment: (personally I would add _more_ empty lines to your example code. Before the packages and after the abstract)

Comment: Where do you see 15 or 16 empty lines?

Comment: I can only see two

Comment: Just to clarify; Do you mean in the DVI/PDF output?

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean

Comment: Oh, you mean the output instead of the latex file. Then this boils down to a pure design question, maybe better ask at https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by default the *article* class uses a lot of whitespace above the title of the paper. If you use a separate title page about 60 points of it.

With regard to the space on top of a regular page,
add `\usepackage{layout}` to your example, and just before the `\end{document}` add:

```
\section{Layout}

\layout
```

Now process and view the document and you will see exactly what the space on top of the page is made up of.

If you want to modify that, have a look at e.g. the `geometry` and `fancyhdr` packages.